# on error, call a function that sends an email in qtp

Tags: error-handling, qtp, hp-uft

I've read error handling concepts & don't seem to make out how we can call a function when an error occurs while executing test script. Here is my requirement

`script 1`

`code with error`

`immediately call a function that sends an email`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First understand the difference between Error and Exception:

> - Predictable Errors   ~~> Error handling (By using "On Error Resume Next")
> - Unpredictable Errors ~~> Exception Handling (By using "Recover Scenario Manager Wizard")

*It's a bad practice to use On Error Resume Next. You should always try to clear all the predictable errors.*

But to give you an example of how you can handle your predictable error using On Error, take a look at this code:

Code with error:

```
...
on error resume next
a = 1/0
If err.number <> 0 then
  'Call function to send email
   Call sendMail()
End If
...

Function sendMail()
    '...
    'Your code to send email
    '...
End Function
```

This is how you can handle your predictable error. But if you have some unpredictable errors than you need to use Recovery Scenario Manager and for that [**Google**](https://www.google.com/search?q=uft%20exception%20handling&oq=UFT%20exce&aqs=chrome.3.0j69i57j0l4.5901j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=uft%20recovery%20scenarios) is your best friend.